# My app suddenly stops

Tags: android, arrays, exception, indexing

I recently uploaded my app to the google play store [Helicopter Combat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.krissini.server)
But every now and then it currupts. I got the error report here:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
    at de.krissini.server.Animation.getImage(Animation.java:36)
```

That's the refered code:

```
public class Animation {

    private Bitmap[] frames;
    private int currentFrame;
    private long startTime, delay;
    private boolean playedOnce;

    public void setFrames(Bitmap[] frames){
        this.frames = frames;
        currentFrame = 0;
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public void setDelay(long d){
        delay = d;
    }
    public void setFrame(int i){
        currentFrame = i;
    }
    public void update(){
        long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
        if(elapsed>delay){
            currentFrame++;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
        if(currentFrame == frames.length){
            currentFrame = 0;
            playedOnce = true;
        }
    }
    public Bitmap getImage(){
        return frames[currentFrame];     // line 36
    }
    public int getFrame(){
        return currentFrame;
    }
    public boolean playedOnce(){
        return playedOnce;
    }

}
```

I understand the error, but how can I prevent it?
I appreciate every answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the misconception that the length of an array is the same as the max index. Where length starts at 1 and index starts at 0, they always differ 1.

Change this:

```
if(currentFrame == frames.length ){
    // your reset code
}
```

To this:

```
if(currentFrame == frames.length - 1){
    // your reset code
}
```